# How to customize an a Mac application toolbar in Xcode 4.3.3?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, interface-builder

In Xcode 3, double-clicking on a toolbar in Interface Builder brings up a configuration window to setup the toolbar's initial appearance – as in what items are initially displayed in the toolbar. However in Xcode 4 double-clicking a toolbar (in the window designer) doesn't do anything.

How can I customize my app windows' toolbars in Xcode 4? I'm using Xcode 4.3.3 on Lion and developing a Mac app.

Note: this is *not* about customizing Xcode's toolbar, but customizing an app's toolbar that is being developed in Xcode

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you double-click the toolbar of the window in Xcode 4's interface editor, a sheet appears with "Allowed Toolbar Items" and "Default Toolbar Items".  (You can also Option-click to see this.)

Although you can't drag items directly into the toolbar of the mock window, the items displayed in that toolbar will change if you drag items into the "Default Toolbar Items" section of the sheet (bottom half of the sheet).  You can also drag around the items in that section to rearrange them.

Note that items must first be dragged into "Allowed Toolbar Items" before they can be dragged into "Default Toolbar Items".

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I couldn't find it earlier because I have some controls already laid out in the window's content view and the toolbar's editing sheet was displaying _underneath_ the content view: https://skitch.com/adib/erdnr/scuttlebutt-toolbar

Comment: How do you change the image on the ToolbarItem?